# Copying a NamedTemporaryFile in Linux results in empty file

Tags: python, linux, temp

I am writing some contents to a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` in Python 3 under Ubuntu 16.04. Under certain circumstances, I want to copy that file to a different location after the writing is done. The problem is reproduced with the following code:

```
import tempfile
import shutil

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t') as tmp_file:
    print('Hello, world', file=tmp_file)
    shutil.copy2(tmp_file.name, 'mytest.txt')
```

`mytest.txt` is empty once the execution is over. If I use `delete=False` when creating the `NamedTemporaryFile` I can inspect its content in `/tmp/` and they are fine.

I know the file cannot be open again while open under Windows as per the documentation, but Linux should be fine, so I wouldn't expect it to be that.

What is happening and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `print()` calls are not being flushed, so when the file is copied nothing has yet been written to it.

Using `flush=True` as a parameter of `print()` fixes the issue:

```
import tempfile
import shutil

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t') as tmp_file:
    print('Hello, world', file=tmp_file, flush=True)
    shutil.copy2(tmp_file.name, 'mytest.txt')
```